# Will a portable ADS-B unit, like Stratus, meet the requirements for my aircraft to be ADS-B equipped by the 2020 mandate?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, ads-b

There is a lot of confusion around what it means to have ADS-B.  What is the minimum equipment required to meet the mandate? Can I use a Stratus to meet that requirement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short version is ***no*** the Stratus will not meet the requirements, and for several reasons.

The final rule requires ADS-B OUT (and the Stratus is only ADS-B IN) that meets particular TSO requirements (see below), and portable units will not.

The FAA has an [ADS-B FAQ](http://www.faa.gov/nextgen/implementation/programs/adsb/faq/#7) on their website which has a lot of great ADS-B information.

The minimum equipment required to meet the mandate is addressed by:

> **What equipment is required by the new rule?**
>
> The rule specifies ADS-B
>   Out equipment compliant with either Technical Standard Order
>   (TSO)-C154c (Universal Access Transceiver) or TSO-C166b (1090 ES).
>   However, to operate in Class A airspace, aircraft are required to
>   equip with avionics certified to TSO-C166b.

The FAQ also specifically addresses the question of portable units and says that they will not be allowed:

> **Will the FAA allow portable/handheld units, or will they have to be panel mounts only?**
>
> Installed transponders and GPS units must meet certification
>   standards. Handheld devices and displays that serve only for
>   situational awareness have more flexibility and are not certified
>   installations. In order to comply with 14 CFR § 91.225 and 91.227
>   aircraft intended to fly in ADS-B airspace must have installed and
>   certified equipment. Portable installations are not compliant to the
>   rule and would only be usable for receiving FIS-B services for
>   situational awareness. The FAA is in the early stages of investigating
>   a portable device for glider aircraft.

Comment: "**Portable installations are not compliant to the rule**" is probably the single most important part of that second quoted section.

Comment: The [SkyGuardTWX Vision-Pro ADS-B Transceiver](http://skyguardtwx.com/UAT_TRANSCEIVER.html) is one such portable device that can provide ADS-B out, which is planned to meet FAA 2020 ADS-B OUT requirement once TSO-C154c certification has been completed.  However, it has not yet been approved.  If it is eventually approved, there might be more portables from other vendors as well.

Comment: I imagine that if the SkyguardTWX is approved that it will have to be permanently mounted to get FAA approval.

Comment: If I remember right, one of the requirements is that the ADS-B out has to be individual aircraft specific. So, that negates the portable ability.

Comment: Each US registered aircraft is assigned a unique mode-s identification.  This id must be programmed into the ADS-B transmitter.  A portable unit can have that information configured for it.  I would be aghast to learn that the portable transmitters did not have a menu option to toggle between several aircraft.